# Write Emmet code In Multiplelines (VsCode)

Tags: html, emmet

community. I'd like to know how to keep writing emmet code in the next line of VSCode after the command gets just too big. Just to keep organized and be able to see all the instructions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option could be that you open another html file in your VScode and make the tab smaller to force the linke break.

I hope that helps you.

However in the documentation it says that a space is a stop symbol where Emmet stops abbreviation parsing.

[Here you find the link to the documentation:](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#notes-on-abbreviation-formatting)

The creator of emmet does not recommend writing to long or to complicated emmet abbreviations, because it's quicker to write shorter and simpler emmet code.

Here is a quote of the website:

> Abbreviations are not a template language, they don’t have to be “readable”, they have to be “quickly expandable and removable”.
> You don’t really need to write complex abbreviations. Stop thinking that “typing” is the slowest process in web-development. You’ll quickly find out that constructing a single complex abbreviation is much slower and error-prone than constructing and typing a few short ones.